# Execute operation periodically while QPushButotn is pressed

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qpushbutton, translate-animation

I've a `QGraphicsView` in which I've some button for translate the view. When I click on one of those button the view is translated. I use the following connection for performing the operation (I'm subclassing `QGraphicsView`:

```
connect(m_upButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){ verticalScrollBar()->setValue( verticalScrollBar()->value() - TranslateFactor ); });
connect(m_downButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){ verticalScrollBar()->setValue( verticalScrollBar()->value() + TranslateFactor ); });
connect(m_leftButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){ horizontalScrollBar()->setValue( horizontalScrollBar()->value() - TranslateFactor ); });
connect(m_rightButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){ horizontalScrollBar()->setValue( horizontalScrollBar()->value() + TranslateFactor ); });
```

It works, but I want also that until one of those button is pressed, I translate periodically the image, so the user can hold down the mouse on the corresponding button for translating the view of the desired amount, instead of clicking many times. How can I obtain this result?

Comment: Have a look at [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QAbstractButton` has a property called `autoRepeat` which does what you want.

Do not forget to look at `autoRepeatDelay` and `autoRepeatInterval` too.

Check the doc for more information.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html